# How to convert dynamically added elements into JSON and back

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization, deserialization

Quick context: This is an application that mimics a magnet board. I want to save the location and id of all draggable elements and later load the file and set those properties and create/delete missing/unnecessary elements. To save the files I utilize Node.js and Electron.

I thought using JSON would be sensible since it can convert directly from JS but how does one do that with an unknown amount of elements?

This Javascript Code adds one of those elements to my page when the corresponding button is pressed:

```
$("#item1").mousedown(function (e){

    var newpin = document.createElement("DIV");
    var pinimage = document.createElement("IMG");

    pinimage.setAttribute("src", "Media/2D_Container_Alfa.jpg");
    pinimage.setAttribute("id", "Alfa");
    pinimage.setAttribute("height", "70px");

    newpin.setAttribute("position","relative");
    newpin.setAttribute("top","20px");
    newpin.setAttribute("left","140px");
    newpin.setAttribute("display","block");

    newpin.setAttribute("class", "draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle");
    newpin.appendChild(pinimage);
    document.body.appendChild(newpin);
});

$("#item2").mousedown(function (e){

    var newpin = document.createElement("DIV");
    var pinimage = document.createElement("IMG");

    pinimage.setAttribute("src", "Media/2D_Container_Bravo.jpg");
    pinimage.setAttribute("id", "Bravo");
    pinimage.setAttribute("height", "70px");

    newpin.setAttribute("class", "draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle");
    newpin.appendChild(pinimage);
    document.body.appendChild(newpin);
});
```

-

Answer (score 0):

You could create the JSON variable outside any functions that might reduce its scope, and then add them in as and when you need to.

```
let myJson = {};

function onMouseDown(event) {
    let thisId = event.id;
    myJson[thisId] = location;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
localStorage.setItem("draggable",JSON.stringify($('.draggable').map(function(){
  return this.id
}).get()));
```

or

```
$.post("saveonserver",{"data":JSON.stringify($('.draggable').map(
  function(){
    return this.id
  }).get()
});
```

Comment: I can't use localStorage since I need to be able to share the generated files.

Comment: Thanks for updating. To avoid further confusion, I am using node.js with electron for the app. So i am utilizing the fs module for saving data.